# Unattended Boot for Encrypted RAID?

Tags: encryption

just recently dabbled into Ubuntu for my home NAS.  I'm using it for a media server as well as my main document repository for my other PCs.

I want to use some sort of disk encryption and RAID 1 (I have one SSD for OS and 2 4TB drives for data).  If I only encrypt the RAID, and still have unattended mount, is there a way to keep the encryption key safe?

I guess I can encrypt the OS drive, but I would lose any unattended boot up.  I only want the unattended boot up in case I need to restart while I'm not at home.

Comment: If you did not encrypt the root volume and kept your data in a separate encrypted volume, then you could at least log in remotely and provide the password to mount the encrypted data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put in the encryption key from the local console during boot if you encrypt the OS drive using Ubuntu's built in full disk encryption.

There appears to be ways of saving an encryption key for a encrypted partition so that only root has access, if that is suitable. If someone else has root access, then you have a bigger problem. The partition that the key is saved to should be encrypted, and that may have to be manually decrypted.

You can also just manually mount the encrypted partition and forgo saving a key file.

I have copied the steps below from this link:
https://www.howtoforge.com/automatically-unlock-luks-encrypted-drives-with-a-keyfile
Credit to original author Stephan Jau

**Step 1: Create a random keyfile**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/root/keyfile bs=1024 count=4
```

This will create a file with random content with the size of 4096 bits (better than a 20/30 character password....). You can use any file to act as keyfile but I think a 4kb file with random content is good suited.

**Step 2: Make the keyfile read-only to root**

```
sudo chmod 0400 /root/keyfile
```

That will make the keyfile readable only by root. If someone get access to this keyfile, then you have a bigger problem on your computer anyway.

Alternatively chown your desired keyfile to root:root and move it into the /root folder

**Step 3: Add the keyfile to LUKS**

LUKS/dm_crypt enabled devices may hold up to 10 different keyfiles/passwords. So, next to having the already setup password we're going to add this keyfile as additional authorization method.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdX /root/keyfile
```

sdX is of course your LUKS device.

First you'll be prompted to enter an (existing) password to unlock the drive. If everything works well, you should get an output like this:

```
Enter any LUKS passphrase:  
key slot 0 unlocked.  
Command successful.
```

**Step 4: Create a mapper**

LUKS devices need to create a mapper that can then be referenced in the fstab. Open /etc/crypttab

```
sudo nano /etc/crypttab
```

and add then a line like this:

```
sdX_crypt      /dev/sdX  /root/keyfile  luks
```

or you can use the UUID of the device:

```
sdX_crypt      /dev/disk/by-uuid/247ad289-dbe5-4419-9965-e3cd30f0b080  /root/keyfile  luks
```

sdX_crypt is the name of the mapper that is being created. You can use here any name e.g. "music" or "movies" or "sfdsfawe" ....

Save and close the file by issuing ctrl-x, enter, enter. Ctrl-x closes nano but first it asks to save the file [yes = enter] and what the name shall be [same name = enter].

What we have done there actually is telling that /root/keyfile shall be used instead of password entry to unlock the drive.

**Step 5: Mount the device in fstab**

Now, we have an unlocked device (well, not yet but when the system is being booted up) and we just need to mount it now. Open /etc/fstab:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and add a new entry like:

```
/dev/mapper/sdX_crypt  /media/sdX     ext3    defaults        0       2
```

Make sure you have the correct mapper name that you added in step 4. Also make sure that the mount point/folder exists. After having added it, save again the file and close it (ctrl-x, enter, enter).

**Step 6: Reboot or remount**

That's it. Now you can reboot and the additional devices should be auto-unlocked and mounted. You can also test it by remounting all devices:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Comment: I just thought of this, but could I put the encryption key on my internal network?  That way, if someone stole my PC, they wouldn't have the encryption key, and data is preserved. I'd have to script in mounting the lan device first.  Thoughts?

Comment: @user747242 Sounds like a good idea to me. I'm not sure how to set it up though